# Decode object with more than 8 fields in Elm

Tags: elm

Given an object with more than 8 fields, how can it be decoded.

Checking the documentation gives up to [object8](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Json-Decode#object8). Not sure how to extend it to cover the other fields. My object contains 18 fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to have a look at the package [Json-Decode-Extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/circuithub/elm-json-extra/2.2.1/Json-Decode-Extra) and in particular to the `apply` and the `(|:)` functions.

For example to decode an object like

```
type alias Location =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , address : String
    , city : String
    , state : String
    }
```

you could construct a decoder using

```
locationDecoder : Decoder Location
locationDecoder =
    succeed Location
        |: ("id" := int)
        |: ("name" := string)
        |: ("address" := string)
        |: ("city" := string)
        |: ("state" := string)
```